# Javascript : Autoplay audio onended function not working

Tags: javascript, api, audio

I'm trying to build a web app that fetches a sound of a bird from an API, plays it and gets a new bird once the old one has stopped playing. As of now it works in Safari & Firefox, but the script stops in Chrome.

```
function init() {
    console.log('init');
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = ("Machines & Birds");

    fetchBirdAPI();
}

function fetchBirdAPI() {
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        getAudio(response);
    });
}

function getAudio(response) {
    if (response.numRecordings !== 0) {
        var birdSrc = (response.recordings[0].file);
        var audio = document.createElement('AUDIO');
        audio.src = birdSrc;

        audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            console.log(audio.duration);
        });

        audio.play();

        audio.onended = function() {
            console.log('Audio Ended');
            init();
        }

    }
    else {
        init();
    }

}
```

So basically the audio.onended doesn't work. Also tried to initiate the audio with audio = new Audio() without any luck.

Really flabbergasted here, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: `but the script stops in Chrome` great, where does it stop logging? Was there an error? Have you tried setting breakpoints? Does the audio play in Chrome? There's a lot of things you can do to help us help you.

Comment: Now that I'm looking a little closer, I'm surprised it works on any browser. If the `audio.src` is a URL, you can't synchronously call `audio.play()`, you have to wait for at least the `canplay` event, but preferably the `canplaythrough` event.

Comment: The audio plays at the initial load in chrome, and logs the duration as well. When ended it just goes silent, with no errors nor logs. I tried putting a breakpoint on the audio.onended and it executes immediately  after the audio.play - thus not waiting for the onended it seems.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The audio.src is a url to a .mp3 file. I'll try the canplay event and get back to you. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm guessing the other browsers probably just let you get away with calling synchronously if the audio file from the URL is in your browser cache, otherwise there's no other way the resource can load synchronously.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see. So what is your suggestion? Chain the onended listener to the promise to make it act synchronously? I am sorry if these are stupid questions, I am still learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166061/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-user2868900).